# If UK left WTO - would it also have to pay divorce settlement?

Tags: international-relations, brexit, trade

World Trade Organisation similarly to EU customs union maintains service and staff it has to finance. And it also requires members to pay membership fees. I haven't managed to find out what happens when a country leaves WTO - it seems it did not happen in the past. Would UK need to pay the WTO if it decides it leave it as well? Would it also be comparable to the payment to EU.

Comment: The EU is a far more complex institution. The EU divorce bill is related with UK commitments as a member. As for WTO, contributions are based on the % of international trade a member did in any given year. I would guess (**this is not an answer**) that a member, at the point of leaving, would have to pay whatever contribution it still owned (these are much, much smaller values than the EU). However leaving WTO would mean entering the trade equivalent of "Dog eats Dog", where no neutral entity would exist to solve disputes (which are extremely common), and scams could become commonplace.

Comment: The EU divorce bill isn't anything to do with membership fees. The UK, through various treaties etc, has legal commitments to pay for certain long term liabilities. Liabilities that will go beyond the date it leaves the EU. These are things like EU staff pensions. Rather than continue paying these ad infinitum, the bill is, essentially, a lump sum that covers their cost. The details, of course, are the subject of much debate.

Answer (score 2):

> I haven't managed to find out what happens when a country leaves WTO - it seems it did not happen in the past.

Because the advantages of staying are overwhelming...

> Would UK need to pay the WTO if it decides it leave it as well? Would it also be comparable to the payment to EU.

Unlikely, if only because there's no substantial WTO budget or funding commitments like there is for the EU. See this question for a breakdown:

[Why does the EU care so much about the UK divorce payment?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/24148/why-does-the-eu-care-so-much-about-the-uk-divorce-payment)