# Would the UK have to pay anything to the EU in case of a no-deal Brexit?

Tags: united-kingdom, european-union, brexit

The EU was [very insistent](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/24148/why-does-the-eu-care-so-much-about-the-uk-divorce-payment) on the UK paying back its obligations to the EU after leaving the Union, as a condition for negotiating a favorable trade deal. But would the UK have to pay back anything if it leaves the EU without a deal of any kind on March 29th?

Comment: When you say 'paying back', do you mean continue to make payments on projects it had previously committed to?

Comment: @JJJ - OP almost certainly means the £39Bn "Divorce bill" rather than any ongoing payments.

Comment: @Valorum The "divorce bill" is mostly to settle ongoing payments on projects we (as part of the EU) already committed too though.

Comment: @TimB  - Indeed. And the principle behind the calculation was that this would essentially be a *final settlement* of outstanding commitments made. Any unforeseen expenses that were incurred (for example, if one of the projects overran in costs) would be covered by the EU.

Comment: I don't think you mean "paying back" in the sense of returning money received from the EU. I think you mean paying monies that would have been payable to the EU if Britain were still a member. And by "have to pay" I think you need to distinguish legal obligations from practical necessity resulting from the desire to maintain working relationships, creditworthiness, etc.

Comment: This question should specify which jurisdiction it aims for. Probably international law or something?

Comment: https://www.express.co.uk/news/politics/1081066/brexit-news-latest-brexit-divorce-bill-european-court-of-justice-ecj - This site suggests not. It notes that since the EU refuses to allow external arbitration and since the UK would no longer be a member post-Brexit, there really wouldn't be any legal mechanism to enforce payment

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The short answer is that people don't all agree whether the UK has any legal commitments to the EU until a withdrawal agreement is ratified, but the House of Lords (and possibly the UK government) have been advised not.

In a [House of Lords report](https://publications.parliament.uk/pa/ld201617/ldselect/ldeucom/125/125.pdf#page=5) dated 4th March 2017 the position was developed which was summarised in the following paragraphs:

> The budget is going to be a contentious early issue during the UK’s negotiations over leaving the EU. It is crucial for both parties. The UK provides approximately 12% of the resources available to the EU budget, and is also a significant net contributor. The removal of the UK’s payments into the budget will require the other EU Member States to agree either to pay more into the budget, or draw less from it. Neither option is without difficulty, and those difficulties may colour the wider Brexit negotiations. The Government will have to consider its stance on continued budgetary contributions in the light of its impact on the wider negotiations, and the economic and political implications will need to be set against one another. The Government has stated that it is open to making payments towards specific programmes in order to cement a cooperative future relationship with the EU but there are already demands from the EU, for much wider contributions.
>
> However, the strictly legal position of the UK on this issue appears to be strong. Article 50 provides for a ‘guillotine’ after two years if a withdrawal agreement is not reached unless all Member States, including the UK, agree to extend negotiations. Although there are competing interpretations, we conclude that if agreement is not reached, all EU law—including provisions concerning ongoing financial contributions and machinery for adjudication—will cease to apply, and the UK would be subject to no enforceable obligation to make any financial contribution at all. This would be undesirable for the remaining Member States, who would have to decide how to plug the hole in the budget created by the UK’s exit without any kind of transition. It would also damage the prospects of reaching friendly agreement on other issues. Nonetheless, the ultimate possibility of the UK walking away from negotiations without incurring financial commitments provides an important context.

The primary [alternative interpretation](https://www.ejiltalk.org/the-brexit-bill-and-the-law-of-treaties/) holds that exercise of Article 50 doesn't rule out Article 70 of the Vienna Convention on the Law of Treaties, which reads:

> Unless the treaty otherwise provides or the parties otherwise agree, the termination of a treaty under its provisions or in accordance with the present Convention:
>
> - releases the parties from any obligation further to perform the treaty;
> - does not affect any right, obligation or legal situation of the parties created through the execution of the treaty prior to its termination.

This all gets a little bit more complicated, since the dispute may or may not need to be settled by the European Court of Justice, which may or may not have the jurisdiction to make a decision after a no deal Brexit.

Answer (score 18):

'Have to' is ill-defined. Just like a regular person, it could decide not to pay. The question is what the consequences of not paying are.

Rather than look at what the EU could do in retaliation, it's interesting to look at the UK itself. The UK has said that it wants to negotiate trade deals with other countries. Since those deals are not yet negotiated, those other countries will look at how the UK deals with its current trading partners. In particular, not making payments you have previously committed to will make one look untrustworthy (just like a regular person not paying their bills).

Given that the UK wants to make these trade deals, they do have a strong incentive to make these payments or at least settle the issue with the EU on good terms.

So do they have to pay? Possibly not. Is it in their interest to pay? Yes. Would it hurt their negotiating position with third countries if they left without paying and the EU publicly challenged them? Definitely.

As pointed out in the comments, this might seem like semantics. The reason it might hurt the UK's future negotiating position is that they have signed a regulation (the Multiannual Financial Framework 2014-2020) which as the name suggests is a budget that ends in 2020.

The UK can argue that it is not legally required to pay its contributions under that regulation because it's no longer bound by EU law, however, that does not take away the fact that they committed to paying.

To support this, I cite a passage from [Channel 4's 'Can we avoid paying the £39 billion Brexit divorce bill?' FactCheck](https://www.channel4.com/news/factcheck/factcheck-can-we-avoid-paying-the-39-billion-brexit-divorce-bill) in which Professor Begg at The LSE responds to the [report in the House of Lords](https://publications.parliament.uk/pa/ld201617/ldselect/ldeucom/125/12503.htm#_idTextAnchor003) that argues the UK needn't pay:

> “The logic goes that when you leave an entity you no longer have a financial commitment” he says. But “the contrary view is that we signed a regulation in 2013 that sets the Medium-Term Budgetary Framework that ends in 2020.”
>
> Hang on, “Medium-Term Budgetary Framework”? EU member states commit to fund projects (like infrastructure investment) in seven-year cycles. We are trying to leave the EU before the end of the current one.
>
> The £39 billion divorce bill is the figure Westminster and Brussels have arrived at to cover the outstanding budget contributions we committed to paying in 2013, and which we would have been paying in 2019 and 2020 were we not leaving the EU. There are also some commitments (like pension contributions) that go beyond 2020, which will be settled in the divorce bill.
>
> Professor Begg says that because the UK signed the 2014-2020 Framework, “you could argue we’re bound to that.”

#### Concrete example

The EU has now implemented some unilateral preparedness measures which are aimed at continuation of EU services for British citizens provided the UK honors its financial commitments. To quote from [today's press release on these preparedness measures](http://europa.eu/rapid/press-release_IP-19-743_en.htm) illustrating how the EU might compel the UK to honor its commitments:

> UK beneficiaries of EU funding would continue to receive payments under their current contracts, **provided that the United Kingdom continues to honour its financial obligations under the EU budget. This issue is separate from the financial settlement between the European Union and the United Kingdom.**

Comment: I think the question is whether the UK has an obligation to pay, not whether it would be forced to.  It's not at all clear, as shown by origimbo's answer, that third countries would see the UK reneging on their obligations if they refused to pay whatever "divorce bill' the EU might insist on.

Comment: I understand your perspective, but the OP's question was whether there is an obligation. Technically it seems dubious, or atleast very debatable, that there is. Whether EU decides to try and extort the money out of the UK later on is just speculation and not quite relevant to the original question.

Comment: @ouflak actually the EU has always said that the divorce settlement had to be negotiated before talking about the future relationship. It's not extortion, realpolitik. The UK's position on demanding special treatment (Cameron in Europe before the referendum) threatening to hurt the European economy (by brexit) was more extortive.

Comment: @RossRidge what is an obligation? The UK is a sovereign nation not bound by (after leaving the rules-based organisation) a rule to pay EU money. All there is left is realpolitik.

Comment: Please don't try to start pointless semantic arguments. For it to "hurt their negotiating position with third countries", the third counties would have to believe the UK had an obligation to the EU that the UK reneged on. You haven't given any reason why these third countries would believe such an obligation exists.

Comment: @RossRidge I edit my answer to expand a bit on that. As for your point that third countries need to believe the UK should pay in this case, that's not entirely true. They might be less inclined or more restrictive in their deal-making if they believed the UK might bail on their future agreement. And to add to that, if they are willing to walk away from a large economy like the EU at their doorstep, it sure would be easy to walk away from commitments to a smaller economy a long way from home.

Comment: But what makes you think that those same third countries should trust the EU either? Afterall, there's been no suggestion that the EU continue payments to the UK post Brexit. Weren't there some obligations on their end as well? Since overall the UK has paid more money into the EU than the EU has paid into the UK, shouldn't *they* be paying the UK a nice divorce bill? I am trying to keep an open mind on this, but I find the idea of punitive measures (including extortion) very worrisome. That's not a way to hold an economic union together. And I don't think this answers the OP's question at all.

Comment: @ouflak you might want to take a look at my edit. It's not really extortion. What happens is that due to the UK's leaving (UK's decision) the EU and possible (we don't know yet) refusal to pay for past commitments that certain services to UK citizens are not covered financially. The Erasmus program is a good example. All countries pitch in to allow students to study abroad, if one country stops paying there is a money gap for students from that country. Now the EU is saying, if you keep paying, you can remain part of the program for a limited time so as not to impact your students too much.

Comment: "Would it hurt their negotiating position with third countries if they left without paying and the EU publicly challenged them?" I'm not really sure how to define this. Maybe extortion is a strong word. But any commitments were clearly made on the assumption that membership would continue indefinitely. So how would leaving without paying, as they are no longer members, 'hurt' them. The only way I can think of is if the EU contacts the third countries and tries to disrupt or interfere with the negotiations until they get the money they want out of the UK. What is the term for this?

Comment: @ouflak everything is public. The EU doesn't have to tell third countries, it's on the news. As for the third countries' perspective, think of it as walking down a boulevard looking for a restaurant. Now you walk past one restaurant and you see the staff loudly arguing with the customer. You will probably walk a bit further to a different restaurants. In this case, countries will probably want to make deals with the UK but they are likely to tread a bit more cautiously.

Comment: But why would they 'tread a bit more cautiously'? I'm still not seeing how the UK is obligated to commitments that everybody in the world can see were made with the obvious assumption that membership would continue indefinitely. The UK has left a large trade union. I'm not sure how that is equivalent to staff arguing with a customer, or how the UK is obligated to continue to commitments, non-intuitively, beyond the end of membership. I want to see how this logic is founded. But it almost seems that other countries might even see *new* trade opportunities here.

Comment: @ouflak these commitments were not indefinitely, they were covered in the current budget which [lasts from 2014 until 2020](http://ec.europa.eu/budget/mff/index2014-2020_en.cfm). As I understand it, the EU is suggests they continue paying the commitments made in that budget and they continue the receive the benefits. Obviously, this is beneficial for UK citizens too. For example, UK students in the EU funded under an EU program may want to finish or take their time to go back rather than being cut off and having to foot the bill or needing to go back without finishing.

Comment: The assumption was that membership would continue indefinitely. How long the commitments were for is irrelevant and could vary from very short term to perpetual. But no matter the length of the commitments, the assumption was that membership would continue indefinitely. Obviously that assumption was fatally flawed. Whether it is 'beneficial' to anybody is also irrelevant. The question is whether there is an obligation. That the EU or the UK might 'look bad' is hardly an obligation, and I'm not even sure that reasoning holds up.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, but it's wrong to see it as "pay back". It's not about money given to the UK by the EU which the EU now wants back.

It's about commitments for future payments which were made by all EU countries, including the UK. A noteworthy example is pensions for EU staff. EU staff has rights to those pensions (just like anyone else); not now, but sometime in the future.

Now, I don't know what recourse the EU has if the UK doesn't fulfill its obligations, but the obligations are still there.

Comment: EU Staff have a right to receive those pensions... *from the EU*. The question is whether the EU has an enforceable right to demand/request payment from the UK to cover those commitments. Assuming they don't, the EU will just have to get the money from elsewhere in their budget

Comment: @Valorum as we read in this question and its answers, having some right does not always mean getting what you owe. In particular, the issue of pensions has already been raised and [the UK and EU disagree (at least in 2016) on the matter](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/2016/08/02/eu-demands-britain-pays-pensions-of-1730-eurocrats-in-wake-of-br/).

Comment: I think this answer starts getting into *tit-for-tat*. The UK has obviously paid way more money into the EU that the EU has paid to the UK. Fair enough considering how that's all calculated and managed, but should the UK expect the EU to continue those payments after a no-deal Brexit? Ofcourse not. I've never even heard anybody suggest it. See where I'm going with that....

Comment: @ouflak I think you can compare it to a contract you might make with your ISP. You pay to have internet on your address for a certain amount per month. Since the ISP has some investment costs (like making a cable network) you make a contract for at least 12 months. Now you want to move with 6 months left on your contract and there is no clause in your contract saying this removes your obligation to pay. Is it then reasonable to expect not to have to pay the remaining 6 months because you will not be able to use the service?

Comment: @JJJ, I think the obvious questions would be then: Is there a term of service for membership in the EU? Does the EU owe the UK money perpetually? Does the UK owe the EU money perpetually? In the contract you use as an example, such things are detailed precisely with all sorts of legalese. When such things aren't defined, it's not so clear. People tend to try and rely on common sense, but that can be hard to apply when the matter is complex and there many emotions involved. Hence the OP's question. Hence the lack of concrete answers.

Comment: I'll give my opinion if it matters. I don't think it is appropriate for the UK to expect the EU to make any further payments after membership ends. I don't think it is appropriate for the EU to expect the UK to make any further payments after membership ends. And I only mean *payments that were related to membership*. That said, they've got bill to pay and we've got bills to pay. They've got things we want, we've got things they want. And it's only money. Surely we can get together afterwords and work something out....

Comment: @ouflak it's not as simple as UK pays EU and vice versa. The divorce bill contains different things (e.g. previous commitments to EU budget, covering pensions, etc.) and the current EU payments to the UK are even broader, think of subsidies to many different organisations (local governments, private organisations, farmers, etc.). Working things out only works if there is a divorce deal. Without a deal, the ECJ might come up with something, but the question is if the UK will comply with that. At this point we can only speculate how a no-deal will work out.

Comment: Let me put it to you like this. What would you say if the EJC actually takes this up and rules quite reasonably that EU should pay the UK a bunch of money due to their 'obligations' and the nature of the balance of payments over the years? Would you agree with that decision? Perhaps then you could argue there is an obligation. This answer is based on the idea that 'the EU wants its money back'. Well the UK wants its money back then too! I think the OP's question was whether these obligations exist at all after Brexit. This answer misses that point.

Comment: Well that's the question isn't? After Brexit, are there any such obligations? The way people are talking about potential EJC rulings and extortion, makes one think 'no'. The way JJJ's answer talks about EU's budget commitments, tries to imply 'yes'. Is there anything in Article 50, or anywhere in fact, that states that if any member, or the EU, makes payment commitments, those commitments extend beyond the end of membership? Right now, the only answers are innuendo and opinion. I don't think that's going to work in any court of law, even the EJC. Nobody seems to have an answer that question.

Comment: My common sense tells me that obviously those commitments were made on an assumption of membership. By both sides. Membership ends, the commitments end. Succinct, logical, and leaves the widest path open for clean-cut future negotiation. But that's not really an answer either.

Comment: Not forgetting that some of those EU pensions will be to British citizens who will be resident in the UK.